# Taking user to a specific page of PDF on iOS (#page=[page number]

Tags: html, pdf, web

When I open this url on Safari on Mac:
https://moviemask.no/pdf/ab.pdf#page=5

It will open the PDF and take me directly to page 5, due to the "#page=5".

Opening the same URL on an iPhone take me to the top of the page.

Is there a way to take the iOS users also to page number 5?

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for replies. Seems like there is no "universal" solution then.